# How to trigger creation/update of another row of record if one row is created/updated in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am receiving a record csv for outside, then when I create or update the entry into the postgresql, I need to create an mirror entry that only have sign differences. This is could be done at program level, I am curious to know would it possible using triggers. 
For the examples I can find, they all end with code,
    `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo()`
And usually deal with checks, add addtional info using `NEW.additionalfield`, or insert into another table. If I use trigger this way to insert another row in the same table, it seems the trigger will triggered again and the creation become recursive. 
Any way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with triggers, the rules of thumb are:

1. If it changes the *current* row, based on some business rules or other (e.g. adding extra info or processing calculated fields), it belongs in a `BEFORE` trigger.
2. If it has side effects on one or more rows in *separate* tables, it belongs in an `AFTER` trigger.
3. If it runs integrity checks on *any* table that no other built-in constraints (checks, unique keys, foreign keys, exclude, etc.) can take care of, it belongs in a `CONSTRAINT` [after] trigger.
4. If it has side effects on one or more *other* rows within the *same* table, you should probably revisit your schema, your code flow, or both.

Regarding that last point, there actually are workarounds in Postgres, such as trying to get a lock or checking xmin vs the transaction's xid, to avoid getting bogged down in recursive scenarios. A recent version additionally introduced `pg_trigger_depth()`. But I'd still advise against it.

Note that a constraint trigger can be created as `deferrable initially deferred`. This will delay the constraint trigger *until the very end of the transaction*, rather than immediately after the statement.

Your question and nickname hint that you're wondering how to automatically balance a set of lines in a double-entry book-keeping application. Assuming so, do NOT create the balancing entry automatically. Instead, begin a transaction, enter each line separately, and have a (for each row, deferrable initially deferred) constraint trigger pick things up from there and reject the entire batch if anything is unbalanced. Proceeding that way will spare you a mountain of headaches when you want to balance more than two or three lines with each other.

Another reading might be that you want to create an audit trail. If so, create additional audit tables and use after triggers to populate them. There are multiple ways to create and manage these audit tables. Look into [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension). (Fwiw, type 6 with a `start_end` column of type `tsrange` or `tstzrange` works well for the audit tables if you're interested in a table's full history *including its history of relationships with other audit tables*.) Use the "live" tables for your application to keep things fast, and use the audit-tables when you need historical reporting.